# How to upgrade old Botchat.js to botchat-es5 version?

Tags: javascript, botframework, chatbot, direct-line-botframework

Since two year, we are managing one chatbot and integrated in MVC web application. We have done many customization(UI related changes like character length, feebacks, texttospeech... etc.)  in chatbot.js file directly. Now we are facing slowness issue with directline due to older chatbot version. Now I want to upgrade it to chatbot-es5.js with our customized changes.

Ideally I should go with React Js project and need to do changes. But I do not have much time need to completed this task in two days... How this is possible?

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for quick response. Can you help me with latest version ?? I am referring this https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat-es5.js

Comment: Take a looks at Web Chat’s documentation on [migrating from v3](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#my-website-is-integrated-with-web-chat-v3-and-uses-customization-options-provided-by-web-chat-no-customization-at-all-or-very-little-of-my-own-customization-that-was-not-available-with-web-chat). Also, take a look at the [Web Chat ES5](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/01.b.getting-started-es5-bundle) sample.

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX  Can I share older botchat.js file with you? will it work? Currently I am using V3... will migrate it inot V4 in next 2 month...

Comment: Sorry...Not worked earlier via Telepathy....

Comment: @JaromandaX started to customize it and its working fine in chrome but not in IE. Can you please help me here... I am getting unauthorize error in directline token only in IE. Please suggest